# Input and output files for mencoder

Tags: video, video-conversion, avi, mencoder

What file types does mencoder accept for input, and what kind of output files can it make besides AVI files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the man page doesn't list the formats (since they're dependent on date and compiler options) and the exact command line is buried in an unexpected place halfway into it.

On the other hand, the mplayer docs have a [whole subsection](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/menc-feat-selecting-codec.html) explaining it.

Answer (score 0):

```
% man mencoder
```

or

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mencoder